# String to \x escaped hex ascii

Tags: python-3.x

i am working with sockets (some DNS stuff) and i can't figure out how from this:

```
a = 'www'
```

make

```
b = b'\x77\x77\x77'
```

I know/think i need to:

1) convert each to hex value with `hex(ord(char))`

2) format it from '0x77' to '\x77'

3) convert it to bytes with `bytes(a,'utf-8')`

I tried many combinations, but i always failed at 2) and generally i think my steps are too complicated. Is there some simple solution to this?

Comment: `b = bytes(a,'ascii')`, but you'll never make python print `b'\x77\x77\x77'` because `b"www"` is printable. but that(s the same.

Comment: You will need to explain what you are trying to do with sockets in more detail. Are you for example trying to get the IP address of a DNS name as a bytes string?

Comment: @BarryScott quite the opposite, i am trying to make DNS response (without the libraries like dnslib), but i am having problems with converting/encoding the string with domain name/ip adress to hex bytes

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks, i didnt realize there could be difference between actual string and things i see after print()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll attempt an answer.

What you wish to do is work with the binary messages being exchanged with a DNS server.

You are wondering how to convert strings and integers into into the binary form.

Have a look at the struct module to pack and unpack binary messages.

You will also need to convert IP addresses from there binary form into strings.

Have a look at socket.inet_ntoa and socket.inet_aton.

Barry